# Should I have 2 different endpoints for GET-ing all Brands and GET-ing Brands based on query parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently I have a back-end endpoint which receives a page query parameter and returns 10 `Brand` entries based on that page. Now I need to be able to GET all brands too, without all the pagination functionality but I'm not sure what is the correct way to do it.

Option 1 - Create 2 endpoints, `'getBrands'` which will return all brands without the pagination functionality, and `'getBrandsByPage'` which will return 10 brands based on the page query parameter.

Option 2 - Have a single endpoint which will check if there is a query parameter `page` first. If there is, it will execute one piece of block, and if there isn't, another. This will make the function bigger and a bit more convoluted with all the `if`s

This is what I have right now:

```
module.exports.getBrands = async (req, res, next) => {
    let page = req.query.page
    let limit = 10
    let offset = ( page - 1 ) * limit
    let brands

    try {
        brands = await Brand.findAndCountAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset,
            order: [
                ['createdAt', 'DESC']
            ]
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

    if (brands) {
        let pages = Math.ceil( brands.count / limit )

        res.status(200).json({
            brands: brands.rows,
            totalItems: brands.count,
            totalPages: pages,
        })
    } else {
        res.status(500)
    }
}
```

The one endpoint alternative would look like this:

```
module.exports.getBrands = async (req, res, next) => {
    let page = req.query.page
    let brands

    try {
        if (page) {
            let limit = 10
            let offset = ( page - 1 ) * limit

            brands = await Brand.findAndCountAll({
                limit: limit,
                offset: offset,
                order: [
                    ['createdAt', 'DESC']
                ]
            })

            if (brands) {
                let pages = Math.ceil( brands.count / limit )
        
                res.status(200).json({
                    brands: brands.rows,
                    totalItems: brands.count,
                    totalPages: pages,
                })
            } else {
                res.status(500)
            }
        } else {
            brands = await Brand.findAll({
                order: [
                    ['createdAt', 'DESC']
                ]
            })

            if (brands) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    brands: brands
                })
            } else {
                res.status(500)
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a REST design point of view, I see no reason for two separate routes to get all brands vs. get all brands (paginated).  This is exactly what a query parameter is for (to specify a modifier for the GET).  Using only one route makes your API more compact and, if you write documentation for it, should make that documentation cleaner.   I would personally design my REST API to optimize the REST design and not to optimize my implementation.

Besides, if you were going to have two completely separate blocks of code for two routes and you like that, you can also have one route with an `if` and then two functions where the if/else just decides which function to call.  You can fit the implementation you like into the better REST design.

You should be able to share most of the code between the two branches.  I don't know your database well enough to suggest code sharing improvements for the paged version, but it seems like you have a bit more copied code than should be required.

In addition, you need to change this:

```
res.status(500);
```

to:

```
res.sendStatus(500);
```

So, that you're actually sending the response, not just setting a state value for a future response.

In addition, you need to be sending a response in the `catch()` handler.

And, probably add a `console.log()` about why you're returning a 500.  The last thing you want to happen is for your server to be returning 500 and have no idea that it's doing that or no idea why it's doing that or not be able to tell a customer why they're getting a 500.

P.S. Note that programming without semi-colons will bite you at some point as there are documented pieces of code where the interpreter will not do what you intended without a semi-colon at the end of the previous line.  One place where this gets you is if you ever declare an IIFE inside a function body or copy in some code someone else wrote that declares an IIFE.

---

Here's one suggestion for the combined route:

```
module.exports.getBrands = async (req, res, next) => {
    const query = {order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]};

    try {
        if (req.query.page) {
            const page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10);

            if (isNaN(page) || page < 1) {
                throw new Error(`Invalid page query "page=${req.query.page}"`);
            }

            // build query for generated paged results
            const limit = 10;
            query.limit = limit;
            query.offset = (page - 1) * limit;

            const brands = await Brand.findAndCountAll(query);

            res.json({
                brands: brands.rows,
                totalItems: brands.count,
                totalPages: Math.ceil(brands.count / limit),
            });
        } else {
            const brands = await Brand.findAll(query);
            res.json({ brands });
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
};
```

I'm guessing that you're using sequelize.  If that's the case, then a successful database query will always return your `brands` object.  There is no reason to check for that to be falsey.  If the DB query fails, the promise will reject and you'll be in the `catch` handler.  If no results are found, then the results will be a zero length array which is a legitimate result set to return.

Comment: "it seems like you have a bit more copied code than should be required." which part are you referring to?

Comment: @Bobimaru - I added a code suggestion to my answer.